# Why is sound not playing in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get an alert sound to play when a certain condition is met. This condition is being met when I test with an `alert()` in place of the sound. Code snippet:

```
if ($scope.incomplete > $scope.incomplete_old) {
  $scope.playAudio = function() {
    var audio = new Audio("{% static 'ping.mp3' %}");
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

Am I missing something here? I don't understand why the sound isn't playing. I'm testing the site locally in Chrome. Is there some other configuration I overlooked?

Comment: $scope.playAudio is a function. Did you try to invoke the function? Something like $scope.playAudio(); or $scope.playAudio = function(){...}();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to your code example `$scope.playAudio` method is never called. Therefor your `audio.play()` will never be executed. To play the sound you have to call the `$scope.playAudio` method.

basically you can do either

```
$scope.playAudio()
```

of you let the function invoke itself

```
$scope.playAudio = function() {
  var audio = new Audio("{% static 'ping.mp3' %}");
  audio.play();
}()
```

further reading: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: You are right, forgot to properly invoke the function. New to angular so thanks for the guidance.

Comment: happy to hear its working now. Can you just mark the answer with the green hook to mark it as `solved` for other users?

Comment: will do, stack overflow delays accepting an answer for 10 min after asking... will accept after that